# Unable to replace & with &amp; in XML uses Preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Need help here. Am not able to replace the '&' with '&' uses Preg_replace in PHP. But, if I do it manually (edited) on the xml file, it works out fine.

Here are the sample:

```
$XMLCharactersPreg = "/[&<>\"\'()^*@+]/";
$XMLPregReplace = "&amp;";
$d_Description = "50% offer & 20% further reduction for member";

if (preg_match($XMLCharactersPreg, $d_Description)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
    $XMLDealDescription = preg_replace($XMLCharactersPreg , $XMLPregReplace, $d_Description);
    echo "$XMLDealDescription <br / >";

} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at htmlentities()?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

```
$XMLDealDescription = htmlspecialchars($d_Description, ENT_QUOTES);
```

The code then becomes:

```
$d_Description = "50% offer & 20% further reduction for member"; 

$XMLDealDescription =  htmlspecialchars($d_Description, ENT_QUOTES);
echo "$XMLDealDescription <br / >";
```

This code works fine - the output is:

```
> g:\Program Files\PHP>php Test\test.php.txt
50% offer &amp; 20% further reduction for member <br / >
```

Any other errors you get (such as XML well-formedness) is likely due to an error somewhere else in your code. (Also, the <br / > tag seems to have a space between the / and the > which isn't needed).

Comment: Hi David_001,

Have tried the code that you posted but it didn't work. Am i missing something here?

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking at the result in a browser, which would display `&amp;` as `&`? So the source contains `&amp;`, but you only see `&` in the browser.

Comment: Hi Sjoerd, 

It shows '&' instead of '&amp;' on the browser. I looked at the XML file, it did not replace the '&' to '&amp;' and received XML parsed error too. 

Looking forward to hear from you as soon.

Thanks

Comment: Your example code works for me, so it is unclear why it is not working for you.

Comment: This is what i received when i run it on the browser based on the above code.

A match was found.50% offer & 20% further reduction for member 

As you can see, the '&' is still remain there? Is that correct? shouldn't it been replaced by '&amp;' ?

Comment: Use the "view source" function of your browser to check whether is has been replaced.